# Formatted XUL Tab caption

Tags: xul

Is there an easy way to have formatted tab captions in XUL? I want  to have a specific part of the tab caption in bold font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No easy way. XUL <tab>'s text is in a <label>, which doesn't give you fine-grained control over parts of the text. You'd have to replace it with a <description> which can contain HTML markup, but this is not a standard thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way perhaps is to put multiple `<label>`'s inside the `<tab>`
Eg :

```
<tabbox>
    <tabs>
        <tab>
            <label style="margin-right: 0px;" value="normal"/>
            <label style="margin-left: 0px; font-weight: bold;" value="bold"/>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
</tabbox>
```

Of course it depends on what it's used for exactly.